# Bootstrap Modal called from Javascript file not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

My goal is this one :

1. I use Javascript to display a button, when a Marker is clicked on a Map
2. When the button is displayed, then if the user click on it, a modal should appear on the page.

The issue I meet :
The modal is not showing at all.

The page is located there :
http://p4547.phpnet.org/bikes/reservation.html

The javascript file is called : interact-version3.js

My HTML code for the Modal :

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" class="modal fade" id="bookingmodal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Réservation</h5><button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="guide">
            <div class="row item">
              <div class="col-md-12 order-md-2">
                <h2 class="item-heading">Signature. <span class="text-muted">Signez pour valider votre réservation.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Titre<br></p>
                <p></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Fermer</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the Javascript section :

```
onMarkerClick(arg) {
  // RÃ©cupÃ©ration du marker concernÃ©
      let marker = arg.target;
  // RÃ©cupÃ©ration des infos
      let info = marker.options.jcdecauxInfo;
      let name = info.name;
      let lowerName = name.toLowerCase();
      let address = info.address;
      let statusStation = info.status;
      let statusStationFr = statusStation.replace('OPEN', '<i class="fas fa-lock-open text-success"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Station Ouverte').replace('CLOSED', '<i class="fas fa-lock text-danger"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Station FermÃ©e');
      let lastUpdate = info.last_update;
      let date = new Date(lastUpdate).toLocaleString();
      let availableBikes = info.available_bikes;
  // Affichage des infos de la station dans l'encart situÃ© Ã  droite :
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = `<h4 title="Adresse" class="details display-5"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt text-danger"></i>&nbsp;DÃ©tails de la station :</h4><div class="text-success"><h5>Station de VÃ©lo'v</h5></div><h6>${name}</h6>`;
      document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = address;
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = statusStationFr;
      document.getElementById("last_update").innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; DerniÃ¨re mise Ã  jour :  ` + date;
      if (availableBikes > 1) {
        document.getElementById("available_bikes").innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>` + availableBikes + `&nbsp;vÃ©los disponibles</strong><br>
          <br>
          <form>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nom :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Votre Nom">
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">PrÃ©nom :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Votre PrÃ©nom">
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#bookingmodal" data-toggle="modal">RÃ©server</button>
          </div>
          </div>
          </form>`;
        }

      else if (availableBikes == 1) {
        document.getElementById("available_bikes").innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>` + availableBikes + `&nbsp;vÃ©lo disponible</strong><br>
          <br>
          <form>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nom :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Votre Nom">
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">PrÃ©nom :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Votre PrÃ©nom">
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#bookingmodal" data-toggle="modal">RÃ©server</button>
          </div>
          </div>
          </form>
          `;
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("available_bikes").innerHTML = `<br><br><h3>Aucun vÃ©lo disponible dans cette station</h3><br><br>`;
      }
    }
```

I hope you can help me on this matter.

Comment: Which button exactly, `Reserver`?

Comment: Yes, the modal should appear when you click on "Reserver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the button has a type of `submit` explicitly (and also by default) inside the form. The browser attempts to submit the form when you click it, resulting in a navigation away from the page. You can prevent this behaviour by changing the button to type `button`

```html
<button type="button" ...>Réserver</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Reserver button is present within the form which is submitting the form and causes the page to reload. You can listen to button `click` and prevent it's default action using `e.preventDefault`.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <button type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks randomSoul ! Nice way to resolve it as well.